# Java: Traversing through an object array, method not working how I intended.

Tags: java, arrays, object

for my code I have an input method that allows the user to input any number of objects with an item name and price into the array. For the assignment I am also suppose to print out an average value of the prices if the name of an object is "peas". Except every time I run the code even with Peas as a name of an object, it outputs that no average was calculated and that it is equal to zero. Thank you

Also another question, I thought it would be better to just make a seperate method to calculate average. However the array has a max size of 1000, and only the numofEntries variable is in the input method. So I am unable to use that to count up to the number of actual objects in the array. How would I work around this?

```
public static void input(Item[] arr) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numofEntries = 0;
    double pricesAdded = 0;
    double average = 0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter item");
        String item = input.next();

        System.out.println("price");
        double price = input.nextDouble();

        if (price == -1) break;

        arr[i] = new Item(item, price);
        numofEntries++;
    }

    for( int j = 0; j < numofEntries; j++) {
        if(arr[j].getName() == "peas" || arr[j].getName() == "Peas") {
            for( int k = 0; k < numofEntries; k++) { 
                pricesAdded = pricesAdded + arr[k].getPrice();
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    if(average == 0) System.out.println("No average output " + average);
        else System.out.println("The average is " + (average = pricesAdded /  numofEntries));

    for ( int i = 0; i < numofEntries; i++)
        System.out.println(arr[i].toString());
}
```

Comment: This is a FAQ, you're comparing strings incorrectly. == is for object identity, use aString.equals(another) to compare strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attempt to calculate the `average` value too late.  By the time the `if` condition is calculated, you haven't assigned a value other than `0` to it, so the `if` condition is satisfied and the `else` block never runs.

Calculate the `average` first, before the `if` statement.  Then, in the `else` block, refer to `average`.

Also, please refer to [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) regarding the line

```
if(arr[j].getName() == "peas" || arr[j].getName() == "Peas") {
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `if` condition to check for `pricesAdded`, not `average`, i.e.

```
if(pricesAdded == 0)
```

Also, you should change at least the string comparison logic.

Try doing

```
  if("peas".equalsIgnoreCase(arr[j].getName()) {
      ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are never really calculating the average.
You can input `numofEntries` as an input variable to your other function.